# How to integrate SharePoint to a public website?

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, public-website

I have a question regarding how to integrate or call a SharePoint list/webpart in a public website?

In the website I have navigation menu item called "Show list" when a user clicks on that it should call the SharePoint site and show the list within the a div that will be the content area.

I hope my question is clear otherwise feel free to ask me if certain things are unclear.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Check my attached picture.

Thanks!
[image]

Comment: Did you happen to figure this out?